# Picasso is loading URL but no picture is shown

Tags: java, android, picasso

I have one of the weirdest problems I've had so far. I am creating an app which sends information about books and authors through different activities. I am sending them with the help of intents. My problem is within the authors section. I am sending name, age and the picture. Name and age are send successfully and to my knowledge with the debugger, the image is sent successfully as well. However, Picasso refuses to load it in ImageView. There are no errors shown and I have no idea what is going on. Here is some code.

This function resets the information in my database:

```
public void resetAuthor()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME_AUTHORS);
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + TABLE_NAME_AUTHORS + "'");

        addBegginingInfoAuthor("J.K.Rowling", 54, "https://www.biographyonline.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/jk-rowling4.jpg");
        addBegginingInfoAuthor("J.R.R. Tolken", 81, "https://www.biography.com/.image/t_share/MTE5NTU2MzE2Mzg4MzYxNzM5/jrr-tolkien-9508428-1-402.jpg");
        addBegginingInfoAuthor("Arthur Conan Doyle", 71, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Arthur_Conan_Doyle_by_Walter_Benington%2C_1914.png");
    }
```

AuthorAdapter class. This is the adapter for my recycler view which displays details about the author. It is also where I start up the intent to move to the other activity:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AuthorsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position))
        {
            return;
        }

        final int author_id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.AUTHORS_COL_1));
        final String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.AUTHORS_COL_2));
        final String age = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.AUTHORS_COL_3));
        final String image = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.AUTHORS_COL_4));

        holder.authorIndex.setText(String.valueOf(author_id));
        holder.authorName.setText(name);
        holder.authorAge.setText(String.valueOf(age));
        holder.authorName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), displayBooksFromAuthor.class);
                intent.putExtra("Author_id", author_id);
                intent.putExtra("Author_name", name);
                intent.putExtra("Author_age", age);
                intent.putExtra("Author_image", image);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

And finally, my DisplayAuthorDetails class which receives the data from the intent and displays it:

```
int author_id = intent.getIntExtra("Author_id", 0);
        String author_name = intent.getStringExtra("Author_name");
        String author_age = intent.getStringExtra("Author_age");
        String author_picture = intent.getStringExtra("Author_image");

        et_name.setText(author_name);
        et_age.setText(author_age);
        et_id.setText(String.valueOf(author_id));
        Picasso.get().load(author_picture).into(author_image);
```

I have the library dependency and also the two permissions in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

`implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828`

The weirdest part of this problem is that when I create a brand new project and try to load an image it loads successfully. Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time

**EDIT**

DatabaseHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Books and Authors.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_AUTHORS = "Authors_table";
    public static final String AUTHORS_COL_1 = "Author_ID";
    public static final String AUTHORS_COL_2 = "Name";
    public static final String AUTHORS_COL_3 = "Age";
    public static final String AUTHORS_COL_4 = "Author_picture";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_BOOKS = "Books_table";
    public static final String BOOKS_COL_1 = "Book_ID";
    public static final String BOOKS_COL_2 = "Author_Foreign";
    public static final String BOOKS_COL_3 = "Title";
    public static final String BOOKS_COL_4 = "Price";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKS + " (Book_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Title TEXT," + "Author_Foreign INT," + "Price TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_AUTHORS + " (Author_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT," + "Age INTEGER," + "Author_picture TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_AUTHORS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertDataBooks(String title, float price) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(BOOKS_COL_3, title);
        contentValues.put(BOOKS_COL_4, price);


        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_BOOKS, null, contentValues);


        if (result == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean insertDataAuthors(String name, int age) {
        SQLiteDatabase mydb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(AUTHORS_COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(AUTHORS_COL_3, age);

        long result = mydb.insert(TABLE_NAME_AUTHORS, null, contentValues);

        if (result == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean addBegginingInfo(int foreign_author_id, String title, double price) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(BOOKS_COL_2, foreign_author_id);
        contentValues.put(BOOKS_COL_3, title);
        contentValues.put(BOOKS_COL_4, price);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_BOOKS, null, contentValues);

        if (result == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean addBegginingInfoAuthor(String name, int age, String image)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(AUTHORS_COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(AUTHORS_COL_3, age);
        contentValues.put(AUTHORS_COL_4, image);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_AUTHORS, null, contentValues);

        if (result == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Integer deleteBook(String index) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME_BOOKS, "Book_ID = ?", new String[]{index});
    }

    public Integer deleteAuthor(String authorIndex) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME_AUTHORS, "Author_ID = ?", new String[]{authorIndex});
    }

    public void resetBookTable() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME_BOOKS);
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + TABLE_NAME_BOOKS + "'");

        addBegginingInfo(1, "Harry Potter", 9.99);
        addBegginingInfo(1, "Fantastic Beasts", 14.99);
        addBegginingInfo(2, "Lord of the Rings", 8.99);
        addBegginingInfo(2, "The Hobbit", 12.99);
        addBegginingInfo(3, "Sherlock Holmes", 6.99);
        addBegginingInfo(3, "Valley of Fear", 7.99);


    }

    public void resetAuthor()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME_AUTHORS);
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + TABLE_NAME_AUTHORS + "'");

        addBegginingInfoAuthor("J.K.Rowling", 54, "https://www.biographyonline.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/jk-rowling4.jpg");
        addBegginingInfoAuthor("J.R.R. Tolken", 81, "https://www.biography.com/.image/t_share/MTE5NTU2MzE2Mzg4MzYxNzM5/jrr-tolkien-9508428-1-402.jpg");
        addBegginingInfoAuthor("Arthur Conan Doyle", 71, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Arthur_Conan_Doyle_by_Walter_Benington%2C_1914.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: check your file size and file format.

Comment: share some details of DatabaseHelper and cross-check DisplayAuthorDetails author_picture is your image url or not

Comment: I edited the question and added DatabaseHelper class. I also checked if author_picture is the URL - it is.

Comment: You can add `setLoggingEnabled(true)` to the Picasso builder.  Also, verify `author_image` is the set properly to the imageview.

Comment: There was nothing our of the ordinary in the logger afetr setting setLoggingEnabled(true). Also I verified that `author_image` is the set property of the ImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of trying I finally found out that to fix this issue I just had to re-install the app on the emulator.